# Dynamic AngularJS data value not being used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have an **AngularJS D3** dial that uses data-actual attribute to set the dial values.

If I hard code in the values it works fine. However, if I use Angular **$scope** variables it doesn't seem to pick up the values.

Working code Example:

```
<div class="widget-container" data-expected="0.90" data-actual="0.30" indicator-widget></div>
```

Non working code:

```
<div class="widget-container" data-expected="0.90" data-actual="{{ dataRemaining | number:2 }}" indicator-widget></div>
```

However, when I look at the source via firebug in both examples it shows me the below. Both the same.

Working result:

```
data-actual="0.30" data-expected="0.90">
```

Non working result:

```
data-actual="0.39" data-expected="0.90">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I gave an answer, but actually I'm not sure what the problem is. You get a value, so it works right?

Comment: @popovitsj Firebug shows the value, but the dial doesn't visualize the data. Its almost like the dial is trying to be rendered before the value is created.

Comment: Try to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem. What seems obvious is that your problem lies with the timing of the execution of the javascript. It can be tricky to combine AngularJS with other JS libraries.